# Newbie music library artist alterations

Tags: python-3.x, scripting

```
"""
Prescript: Is there a plugin for python for selecting and altering the artist of an mp3 file.
As well as running this script on a library of music, how would one do it?

The purpose of this function is to scan through the artist of the mp3 file and return how many
semi-colons are there as well as the string
"""


def scanner():
    music_artist = input('Music_Artist_String Goes Here: ')
    changes = 0
    for letter in music_artist:
        if letter == ";":
            changes += 1
        return changes, music_artist


"""
The purpose of this function is to see how many semi-colons are in the mp3 file's artist section
and adjust them accordingly. Cannot figure out to get this to work.
"""


def title_alteration(changes, music_artist):
    if changes == 0:
        pass
    if changes == 1:
        music_artist.replace(';', ' feat. ')
    if changes == 2:
        music_artist.replace(';', ' feat. ', 1)
        music_artist.replace(';', ' & ', changes - 1)
    if changes >= 3:
        music_artist.replace(';', ' feat. ', 1)
        music_artist.replace(';', ', ', changes - 1)
        music_artist.replace(';', ' & ', ***)
    print(music_artist)
    return music_artist


def main():
    title_alteration(*scanner())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

1. Will change scanner once I figure out how to use this script on existing mp3's, came here to ask how to do that.
2. I cannot get my second function to alter a music title script such as "Lil Skies;Migos" to "Lil Skies feat. Migos". The result of the second function altering the artist should be: "Artist;Artist" to "Artist feat. Artist", "Artist;Artist;Artist" to "Artist feat. Artist & Artist" or "Artist;Artist;...;Artist" to "Artist feat. Artist, Artist, ... & Artist".

Post-Script: Cannot figure out what to put at '***' to make the function work on strings of ";" 3 or more.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def title_alteration(music_artist_string):
    music_artist_string = music_artist_string.replace(';', ' feat. ', 1)
    semicolon_count = music_artist_string.count(';')
    music_artist_string = music_artist_string.replace(';', ', ', semicolon_count-1)
    music_artist_string = music_artist_string.replace(';', ' & ')
    return music_artist_string


def main():
    music_artist_string = 'Artist1'
    music_artist_string = title_alteration(music_artist_string)
    print(music_artist_string)

    music_artist_string = 'Artist1;Artist2'
    music_artist_string = title_alteration(music_artist_string)
    print(music_artist_string)

    music_artist_string = 'Artist1;Artist2;Artist3'
    music_artist_string = title_alteration(music_artist_string)
    print(music_artist_string)

    music_artist_string = 'Artist1;Artist2;Artist3;Artist4'
    music_artist_string = title_alteration(music_artist_string)
    print(music_artist_string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Artist1
Artist1 feat. Artist2
Artist1 feat. Artist2 & Artist3
Artist1 feat. Artist2, Artist3 & Artist4
```